# jQuery replace button dropdown list with a label on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a button dropdown list as a column in each row. When the users selects from the dropdown I want the dropdown to be replaced by a label that reflects the selection they have made. I have this working but it will only on the first dropdown list.

The rows are each identical to this, except different row numbers:

```
<tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>
        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group" id="MACdropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="move" href="#">Move Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="swap" href="#">SWAP Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="add" href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="cancel" href="#">Cancel Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="change" href="#">Change Assets</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entire Site Move</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </td>
      <td>4534-23423</td>
      <td>123-234</td>
      <td>346</td>
      </tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#move' , function(){
      $('#MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">MOVE</span></a>');
        })
    $("#MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#swap' , function(){
      $('#MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">SWAP</span></a>');
        })
    $("#MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#add' , function(){
      $('#MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">ADD</span></a>');
        })
    $("#MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#cancel' , function(){
      $('#MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CANCEL</span></a>');
        })
    $("#MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#change' , function(){
      $('#MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CHANGE</span></a>');
    })


  });
```

I would rather not have to make separate sets of JS statements for each dropdown list on the page. Example: changing #MACdropdown to #MACdropdown1 etc. and making separate functions.

Check out the Fiddle for more info: http://bootply.com/75941

Comment: use class selector instead of the id selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to each dropdown using its class rather than the ID which, as you know, must be unique. IF you repeat the above code several times, you'll still be adressing only the first dropdown .

HTML:

```
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>
        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group" class="MACdropdown" id="MACdropdown1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="move" href="#">Move Assets</a></li>
            <li><a class="swap" href="#">SWAP Assets</a></li>
            <li><a class="add" href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
            <li><a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel Assets</a></li>
            <li><a class="change" href="#">Change Assets</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entire Site Move</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </td>
      <td>4534-23423</td>
      <td>123-234</td>
      <td>346</td>
      </tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a.move' , function(){
      $(this).closest('.MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">MOVE</span></a>');
        })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a.swap' , function(){
      $(this).closest('.MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">SWAP</span></a>');
        })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a.add' , function(){
      $(this).closest('.MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">ADD</span></a>');
        })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a.cancel' , function(){
      $(this).closest('.MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CANCEL</span></a>');
        })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a.change' , function(){
      $(this).closest('.MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CHANGE</span></a>');
    })


  });
```

As you see, I'm not using ids at all. Each select behaves the same, and its children controls just affect him (you could also use the parent selector instead of closest('.MACDropdown') but I chose the latter in case you change a bit your layout.

Comment: Works perfect I tried using classes, I know IDs are unique but when I would make the selection it would change all the .MACdropdown on the page. The addition of closest worked perfectly, I forgot about .parent too!

Comment: I'm not sure parent would do it, as 'this' refers to the clicked anchor element, parent would select it's <li> tag if I'm correct.

Comment: @RichardRaby I meant parent().parent().parent() (repeat until you reach the wanted element. That leaves you tied to yout current layout)

Comment: Now get this to try and work once I add a row to the table when the plus sign is clicked. http://bootply.com/75955

Comment: In that case you should delegate the listener to it's parent container. For example:  



      $(document).on('click' , '.MACdropdown a.move' , function(){
      $(this).closest('.MACdropdown').replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">MOVE</span></a>');
        })

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Change your id's to classes and use the following. Using duplicate id's will mean when used in a selector, it will just select the first element it finds, a class selector will select all items with that class. Inside each onclick function, it then uses 'this' to refer to itself before making the change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#move' , function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">MOVE</span></a>');
    })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#swap' , function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">SWAP</span></a>');
    })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#add' , function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">ADD</span></a>');
    })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#cancel' , function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CANCEL</span></a>');
    })
    $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#change' , function(){
      $(this).replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CHANGE</span></a>');
    })


});
```

Comment: This only replaces the anchor tag within the li, I need the whole div.MACdropdown to be replaced.

Comment: Amenadiel's answer should do it. 'this' must reference the clicked link, so you want to navigate from there upwards to the dropdown control before replacing it (my answer was posted in haste, apologies).

Answer (score 0):

Only one id per element per page.  Use classes instead.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#move' , function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">MOVE</span></a>');
            })
        $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#swap' , function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">SWAP</span></a>');
            })
        $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#add' , function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">ADD</span></a>');
            })
        $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#cancel' , function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CANCEL</span></a>');
            })
        $(".MACdropdown").on('click' , 'a#change' , function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().replaceWith('<a href="viewassets-move.html"><span class="label label-danger">CHANGE</span></a>');
        })


      });
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tbody><tr>
          <td>1.</td>
          <td>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group" class="MACdropdown">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="move" href="#">Move Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="swap" href="#">SWAP Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="add" href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="cancel" href="#">Cancel Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="change" href="#">Change Assets</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entire Site Move</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td>4534-23423</td>
          <td>123-234</td>
          <td>346</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td>2.</td>
          <td>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group" class="MACdropdown">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="move" href="#">Move Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="swap" href="#">SWAP Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="add" href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="cancel" href="#">Cancel Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="change" href="#">Change Assets</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entire Site Move</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td>4534-23423</td>
          <td>123-234</td>
          <td>346</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td>3.</td>
          <td>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group" class="MACdropdown">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="move" href="#">Move Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="swap" href="#">SWAP Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="add" href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="cancel" href="#">Cancel Assets</a></li>
                <li><a id="change" href="#">Change Assets</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entire Site Move</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </td>
          <td>4534-23423</td>
          <td>123-234</td>
          <td>346</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a page, you can't use same css id , if you use it will select only first occur id.

> use **unique class for each rows**. change the code like this.. and
>
> use unique id's to drop down links also., then only we can find,
>   which row buttion is clicked (increment that id's too )

```
   <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>
        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group" id="MACdropdown_1"> // should increment for each row
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="move_1" href="#">Move Assets</a></li> 
            <li><a id="swap_1" href="#">SWAP Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="add_1" href="#">Add Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="cancel_1" href="#">Cancel Assets</a></li>
            <li><a id="change_1" href="#">Change Assets</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entire Site Move</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </td>
      <td>4534-23423</td>
      <td>123-234</td>
      <td>346</td>
      </tr>
```

On your js, onclick dropdown, extract the last numeric field, then update dropdown with that numeric value.